# Python databases

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I would like run a script that will ping some servers from a database and update a field in a database.

My database is sqlite and the layout is:

`name IP last_poll status`

Typically the values will be:

`HQ 192.168.1.1 12:00 2016-01-01 online`

The idea is to have a loop to select the data from the database but how can I insert the result back into the same row?

I have the basic setup where I can ping a single host:

```
import os
hostname = "192.168.1.1"
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)

if response == 0:
    print "online"
```

I could iterate through the tuple if I select the data but I don't know how I can insert it back into the rows.

Comment: Use the `UPDATE` command. Assuming you read the row into a tuple `foo`, it would look something like `conn.execute("UPDATE TableName SET last_poll=%d WHERE IP='%s'", (foo[1], new_update_time))`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I have a list of tuples now achieved with this:

`def read_from_db():
c.execute('SELECT ip FROM sites')
data = c.fetchall()
hostnames = tuple(sum(data, ()))`

`for h in hostnames:
    responses = tuple(os.system('ping -c 1 ' + h) for h in hostnames)`

`z = zip(hostnames, responses)`

That gives me a list of tuples:

`[(u'10.0.0.260', 512), (u'10.0.0.254', 0)]`

But how can that be used to update the database in a batch checking where the IP and updating the status with a code?